# YTD and MTD of Mutual Fund using PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a NAV history CSV and I have to calculate the YTD and MTD performance of a Mutual Fund on a given date using the NAV.

My CSV looks like this.

```
MutualFundName  NAV Date
A               2   2022-02-03
A               2.2 2022-02-02
A               2.1 2022-02-01
B               3   2022-02-03
B               2.9 2022-02-02
B               2.7 2022-02-01
C               6   2022-02-03
C               5.5 2022-02-02
C               5.9 2022-02-01
```

Where I have a corresponding NAV value for each Mutual Fund on a given date.

I have to calculate the YTD and MTD of each Mutual Fund on the current date.

YTD formula is

`((NAV(end) - NAV(start)) / NAV(start)) * 100`

where `NAV(end)` is the current date and `NAV(start)` is 1st January of that year.
Similarly, for MTD it will be and `NAV(start)` will be the 1st of the given month and year.

I have to write a pyspark job to achieve it. Currently, I have the CSV data in a DataFrame.

Expected O/P for MTD for 3rd Feb 2022 will be

```
MutualFundName  MTD
A               -4.761904762
B               11.11111111
C               1.694915254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter where `Date` is equal to `current_date` or first day of current month, then group by `MutualFundName` and apply your formula:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.filter(
    "Date = current_date or Date = date_trunc('mm', current_date)"
).groupBy("MutualFundName").agg(
    ((F.max(F.struct("Date", "NAV"))["NAV"] - F.min(F.struct("Date", "NAV"))["NAV"]) /
     F.min(F.struct("Date", "NAV"))["NAV"] * 100
     ).alias("MTD")
)

result.show()
#+--------------+------------------+
#|MutualFundName|               MTD|
#+--------------+------------------+
#|             A|-4.761904761904765|
#|             B|11.111111111111104|
#|             C|1.6949152542372818|
#+--------------+------------------+
```

---

For Spark 3+, you can use `max_by` and `min_by` function instead of struct ordering in the aggregation:

```
result = df.filter(
    "Date = current_date or Date = date_trunc('mm', current_date)"
).groupBy("MutualFundName").agg(
    ((F.expr("max_by(NAV, Date)") - F.expr("min_by(NAV, Date)")) /
     F.expr("min_by(NAV, Date)") * 100
     ).alias("MTD")
)
```